# Como pegar o valor de um registro sql e armazenar em variável PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela sql da seguinte forma:

```
usuario 
(`matricula` varchar(20) not null primary key,
  `nome` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(15) NOT NULL);
```

No php estou tentando pegar o nome de um usuário que tenha a matrícula especificada pelo `mysqli`:

```
$nomeUsuario = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE matricula = $matricula");
```

Porém não está dando muito certo, mesmo utilizando o `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Alguma ideia do que esteja errado?

Comment: Ola @Amanda, Bem vinda ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour] -- **Seu código apresenta algum erro?** Se sim vale a pena colocar na pergunta. **Como você esta usando a variavel `$nomeUsuario`?**, **A `$conexao` esta ok?**, essas informação vão ajudar a comunidade a entender melhor seu problema. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a coluna matrícula, a qual é sua chave primária, é sua chave primária, é do tipo `varchar` ; então sua SQL precisa receber **strings** e não **números inteiros**, como seu exemplo. O código corrigido:

```
$nomeUsuario = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE matricula ='". $matricula."');
```

Algumas dicas que podem te ajudar:

1. Ter um varchar como chave primária pode deixar suas requisições um pouco mais lentas, é recomendável ter uma coluna que se auto preenche com valores inteiros, principalmente para ter mais efetividade em unir as tabelas com inner join.
2. Você pode ver o erro do SQL em seu php se utilizar um código este aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

```php
  if (!mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE matricula = $matricula")
   {
             echo("Descrição do erro: " . mysqli_error($conexao));
   }
```